# how to calculate a value from different colum sections in r?

Tags: r

I have a table of data with three variables/columns with ca. 100 rows.

I am trying to calculate a value from different column sections and fill them into the specific place in a new column that i have created.

The for loop i have  doesn't work...

```
for(i = 5:nrow(zz)){
 zz[i,4]<-(zz[i,2]*5+zz[i-1,2]*4+zz[i-2,2]*3+zz[i-3,2]*2+zz[i-4,2])/15
}
```

zz is a table with 4 columns

i think there is a problem with syntax, because i haven't used r programming language a lot. thanks.

Comment: Please add what you are trying to accomplish using a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an equal sign in `for` when it should instead be `in`

```
zz <- matrix(rnorm(400), ncol = 4, nrow = 100)


for(i in 5:nrow(zz)){
    zz[i,4]<-(zz[i,2]*5+zz[i-1,2]*4+zz[i-2,2]*3+zz[i-3,2]*2+zz[i-4,2])/15
}
```